# Why is this returning false

Tags: java

I'm working on a Sudoku program, and i have a boolean function
and inside the function, before each return false statement, i have a print statements to show me where it returned false, Right? well my code below managed to return false without printing anything to screen, altho it did manage to print wtf,ayy,wtf, and a final ayy. which also doesnt make sense because ayy is inside a for loop of 9... anyhelp would be awesome.

```
if (checkBytez() == false){
    fieldsPary[a][b] = 0;
    fields[a][b] = 0;
    count++;
    System.out.println("ayy");
    if (count > 1)
        break;
    continue;
}


public boolean checkBytez() {
    byte temp = 45;
    byte[] arr;
    ArrayList<Byte> arr2 = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for (byte i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.println("wtf");
        temp = 0;
        arr = refillArr();
        arr2 = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        for (byte j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (fields[i][j] != 0){
                temp += fields[i][j];
                arr2.add(fields[i][j]);
            }
        }
        if (arr2.size() > 0){
            for (byte b:arr)
                if (arr2.contains(b) == false){
                    temp += b;
                    System.out.println(temp - b + " +=  " + b);
                }

            if (temp != 45){
                System.out.println("false1");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (temp != 45){
            if (temp != 0)
                System.out.println("false2");
                return false;
        }

    }
    for (byte i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        temp = 0;
        arr = refillArr();
        arr2 = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        for (byte j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (fields[j][i] != 0){
                temp += fields[j][i];
                arr2.add(fields[j][i]);
            }
        }
        if (arr2.size() > 0){
            for (byte b:arr)
                if (arr2.contains(b) == false){
                    temp += b;
                }

            if (temp != 45){
                System.out.println("false1");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (temp != 45){
            if (temp != 0)
                System.out.println("false2");
                return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

how is this possible
edit: output:
wtf
ayy
wtf
ayy

Comment: debug it and find out

Comment: debug the flow..

Comment: Not your direct issue, but using `byte` for your loops like `for (byte i = 0; i < 9; i++) {` is pointless. It will be widened to an `int` in the `i < 9`, in the `i++`, when you use it in array indices etc. Just use `int`.

Comment: i have print statements before the return statements, ergo, it will tell me when it returns false, and it didnt.

Comment: @AndyTurner noted, Thanks.

Comment: @JacobBurgess but adding those `System.out.println` statements actually changed the flow. This is why using an actual debugger would be preferable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is an `if` statement without braces:

```
if (temp != 0)
    System.out.println("false2");
    return false;
```

That code is equivalent to:

```
if (temp != 0) {
    System.out.println("false2");
}
return false;
```

*Always* use braces for `if` statements, to avoid this sort of thing. Formatting the code in your IDE would have given you a hint about this as well, as it would have outdented the return statement.

As an aside, I would also recommend using:

```
if (!checkBytez())
```

instead of

```
if (checkBytez() == false)
```

... while it doesn't matter in *that* particular case, avoiding comparing against Boolean literals can prevent mistakes, e.g.:

```
if (someValue = false)
```

which is valid code, but performs an assignment instead of a comparison.